# Discover card widget not working

Tags: iphone, ios, dns, widgets

I have tried many different things to try and solve this issue:

- restarted my iPhone
- uninstalled and reinstalled the the app.
- Removed and added the widget
- Cleared my cache
- tried using cellular data

Nothing seems to work. Quick view in the app and the app work as intended. My banking widget works as well.

The widget says that I’m not connected to the Internet.

I have and iPhone 11 pro running iOS 16.4.1.

Update: I did some network research and when I go to the app, the DNS reply is different than the widget for the same domain. I’m not sure why because they both use the same connection, perhaps something faulty in the code?

If I do a manual nslookup on the domain, mapi.discoverbank.com, I get the IP that doesn’t connect. The app had no trouble finding the correct ip address.

How can I resolve this issue

Comment: Do your other apps/widgets work as expected?  If they do, it’s not clear what your expectations are here because if everything else works then the issue is the widget and it falls under the realm of the developer to fix.

Comment: Yes, everything else works as expected. I guess I’ll have to wait for an update to hopefully solve this issue. Thank you for your response.